# Array of objects - set keys by object field value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have associative array of objects. I want to set keys in that array by object field value. All questions I looked at were about grouping, but in my case these values are always unique.

What I have:

```
<?php

$demo = [
    (object) ['key' => 'a', 'xxx' => 'xxx'],
    (object) ['key' => 'b', 'xxx' => 'xxx'],
    (object) ['key' => 'c', 'xxx' => 'xxx']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($demo as $item) {
    $result[$item->key] = $item;
}

die(print_r($result));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => a
            [xxx] => xxx
        )

    [b] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => b
            [xxx] => xxx
        )

    [c] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => c
            [xxx] => xxx
        )
)
```

But is there better way, without loop? What would be shortest solution, some one-liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [array_combine()](https://php.net/array_combine) and [array_column()](https://php.net/array_column).

`array_column()` to get the keys, and `array_combine()` to build the array using the extracted keys and objects as values.

```
$demo = [
    (object) ['key' => 'a', 'xxx' => 'xxx'],
    (object) ['key' => 'b', 'xxx' => 'xxx'],
    (object) ['key' => 'c', 'xxx' => 'xxx']
];

print_r(array_combine(array_column($demo, 'key'), $demo));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => a
            [xxx] => xxx
        )

    [b] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => b
            [xxx] => xxx
        )

    [c] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => c
            [xxx] => xxx
        )

)
```

See a [working demo](https://3v4l.org/uKsdS).

Comment: I don't think this works if the objects do not implement ArrayAccess

Comment: This works with custom objects with public properties : demo https://3v4l.org/FodFh